# Tensorflow android demo . How to retrain?

Tags: android, tensorflow

I am trying to use the android TensorFlow demo TF classify app code to change training data. I want to use two flowers instead just like in this demo: https://medium.com/@daj/creating-an-image-classifier-on-android-using-tensorflow-part-3-215d61cb5fcd

the problem is according to the tutorial im following it says that there should be a assets folder generated and i can put my training data in there and then re-build.
But when i built the tensorflow android demo there was no assets folder created in bazel-bin or in android src folder. i also did a search for assets folder and nothing.
I am using the docker container outlined in the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create assets folder by yourself.

If you are using Android Studio, then select menu from

File -> New... -> Folder -> Assets Folder and then paste the files to that folder.

FYI, you also have to create libs folder (in project level) and jniLibs folder.

**UPDATE:**

After putting those graph file(.pb) and label file (.txt) in that Assets folder, you have to specify and load them from your code.

For example, assuming that your graph file name is "my_graph.pb" and label file is

"my_labels.txt", then specify them as :

```
private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/my_graph.pb";
private static final String LABEL_FILE ="file:///android_asset/my_labels.txt";
```

and you can load them when initializing:

```
           classifier = TensorFlowImageClassifier.create(
                    getAssets(),
                    MODEL_FILE,
                    LABEL_FILE,
                    IMAGE_SIZE,
                    IMAGE_MEAN,
                    IMAGE_STD,
                    INPUT_NAME,
                    OUTPUT_NAME);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error initializing TensorFlow!", e);
        }
```

Of course don't forget to define other constants (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_MEAN, etc..) with appropriate values before initializing.

**UPDATE 2**
FYI, here's sample project's app structure in android studio:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried creating the asset folder and i then placed the info files there but it did not work. They were just ignored and it built the original project. Is there since caching going on?

Comment: When i build the sample project there is no assets folder generated actually. So looks like it's not even used. Please comment and did you try it yourself?

Comment: @j2emanue ,  sure I'm using it without any problem. I'm updated my answer. At least you have to put graph and label files somewhere to use tensorflow, it doesn't have to be assets folder though, as long as you can specify those files location somewhere within the proejct.

Comment: I checked the sample application, and I can see the assets folder exists. You couldn't find the folder in app structure(Android)? weird...I updated again with a screenshot of sample app structure.

Comment: I'm not sure what sample project you are looking, but if you want reuse that project with your own graph then search the project to find where the sample graph and label is located and replace them with yours. 

If you don't want to change a single line of the sample codes, then rename your files to the existing sample files and overwrite them. Then you should good to go.